# c++ stack of shared pointers delete element

Tags: c++, pointers

I don't know how can i delete element with .top() when i have a stack of shared pointers.

My class (something like this):

```
Class
{
public:
    Class();
    ~Class();
    void popState();

private:
    std::stack<std::shared_ptr<State> > states;
}

void Class::popState()
{
    delete this->states.top();
}
```

I have error at "delete this->states.top()": expression must have a pointer type. 
How it should be written correctly?

Comment: The whole point of shared pointers (of smart pointers in general really) is so you dont have to delete anything manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A large part of the reason for using `shared_ptr` is that you **don't** have to delete the object that it points to. The destructor of the last `shared_ptr` that points at the object deletes the object. So remove that `delete` line from the destructor. There's nothing you need to do.

Comment: *The destructor of the last shared_ptr or weak_ptr that points at the object deletes the object.* Wrong, the weak pointer is a non-owning reference. (see [the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr)) If it held the reference to the object you wouldn't have to convert it to a share_ptr to access it, but you do.

Comment: @Borgleader - fixed. Too early in the morning.

Comment: But when i want to pop this element like this: this->states.pop() then this shared ptr is deleted automatically?

Comment: @nolbek - no. The `shared_ptr` object is **destroyed**, just like any other auto variable. Its destructor deletes the pointee.

Comment: @nolbek You class' default destructor will call std::stack's destructor which in turn deletes all of its elements, and the shared_ptr will delete the pointes. [See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06078edae04b4373)

Comment: So, this->states.pop() is enough, right? I'm sorry for this stupid questions, but i'm learning c++

Comment: @nolbek [Yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb630d10c09117c6), though you could have verified that yourself by adding print statements like I just did.

Comment: @nolbek - "`this->states.pop()` is enough, right?" -- yup. Sorry to have not clearly stated the point. The call to `pop()` removes the element and destroys it; if there are no other `shared_ptr` objects that point to the same object, the pointee gets deleted.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Btw; you may want to drop the redundant `this->`. It is not needed.